# Populate select options based on another select with Vue and JSON

Tags: json, vue.js

Need help creating a dynamic search form with select options for Districts, Regions and locations.
Regions select must be populated based on the District and Locations based on the Regions

The data is stored on a JSON file with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "level": 1,
        "code": 1,
        "name": "District"
    },
    {
        "level": 2,
        "code": 101,
        "name": "Region"
    },
    {
        "level": 3,
        "code": 10101,
        "name": "Location"
    }
]
```

here´s the complete JSON file:
https://gist.github.com/tomahock/a6c07dd255d04499d8336237e35a4827

### html snippet

```
<select name="district" v-model="district">
    <option value=''>Select District</option>
    <option v-for="district in filterDistricts" :value="district.code">
        {{ district.name }}
    </option>
</select>
<select name="region" v-model="region">
    <option value=''>Select Region</option>
    <option v-for="region in filterRegions" :value="region.code">
        {{ region.name }}
    </option>
</select>
<select name="location" v-model="location">
    <option value=''>Select Location</option>
    <option v-for="location in filterLocations" :value="location.code">
        {{ location.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

### javascript snippet

```
data() {
    return {
        searchData: [],
        districts: [],
        regions: [],
        locations: []
    }
},
created(){
    this.fetchData();
},
computed: {
    filterDistricts() {
        return this.districts = this.searchData.map(res => ({
            level: res.level,
            code: res.code,
            name: res.name
        }))
        .filter( res =>  res.level === 1) 
    },
    filterRegions() {
        return this.regions = this.searchData.map(res => ({
            level: res.level,
            code: res.code,
            name: res.name
        }))
        .filter( res => res.level === 2)
    },
    filterLocations() {
        return this.locations = this.searchData.map(res => ({
            level: res.level,
            code: res.code,
            name: res.name
        }))
        .filter( res => res.level === 3) 
    }
},
methods: {
    fetchData(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/json/searchData.json')
        .then((response) => (
            this.searchData = response.data
            ))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

I think I need to associate de code numbers, but I can´t figure out how.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That JSON structure isn't very useful. How do sub-elements (regions / locations) relate to their parents? If it's via `code`, could you show some diversity to illustrate the relationship?

Comment: Edited the question.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I wouldn't bother with those `map` calls since you're only reproducing the same structure.

Second, I'll assume that each sub-element (region / location) relates to its parent (district / region) via a pattern where each sub's `code` is prefixed with the parent code, followed by a two-digits, zero-padded.

With that in mind, try this in your `computed` properties

```
filterDistricts () {
  return this.searchData.filter(({ level }) => level === 1)
},
filterRegions () {
  // assuming you don't want any selections until a district is chosen
  if (!this.district) return []

  const codeCheck = new RegExp(`^${this.district}\\d{2}$`)
  return this.searchData.filter(({ level, code }) =>
      level === 2 && codeCheck.test(code))
},
filterLocations () {
  if (!this.region) return []

  const codeCheck = new RegExp(`^${this.region}\\d{2}$`)
  return this.searchData.filter(({ level, code }) =>
      level === 3 && codeCheck.test(code))
}
```

---

Extra notes...

From looking at your template, it seems you should initialise your `data` as

```
data () {
  return {
    searchData: [],
    district: null,
    region: null,
    location: null
  }
}
```

Computed properties don't need to be stored in data properties so you don't need `districts`, `regions` and `locations`.

Your *label* options should also be disabled so they cannot be selected, eg

```
<option disabled value="">Select Region</option>
```

Comment: Edited the question with a link to JSON file i´m using.Please check

Comment: @user3094954 yes I saw and it looks like my guess around the `code` pattern was correct